# Totaling Time Records to Accurately Reflect Hours:Minutes:Seconds

Tags: excel

I would like to add all of my times to show the summed total time as HH:MM:SS. For some reason I can't get an accurate value but the Excel window does show that it is possible. Can you help me?

```
Times:
2:18:36
5:53:29
4:50:25
0:00:54
6:37:56
5:33:16
6:01:17
5:03:18
0:01:58
6:25:36
6:15:34
6:35:46
4:28:34
4:58:38
0:05:11
7:13:04
6:43:08
5:00:08


Sum using [hh]:mm = 9564:18

Sum I want =  84:06:48
```

[image: Excel Window]

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this.  When I copy/paste your provided time values into a new workbook, and then just use a simple `=SUM(A:A)` formula, I get the expected result `84:06:48`.

Comment: @tigeravatar I display the desired value when i select the column (after copied data and pasted, did not format, same as OP).  Using `=sum(A:A)` i get `3.504722222`, or if i convert to time, i get `12:06:48`.  However, if i put the sum directly under the cells with the copy/pasted values, i get the correct value, formula `=SUM(A2:A19)`

Comment: @Cyril It was a newly opened workbook, so cells were General to begin with, and after pasting in the provided time values the cell format shows as `[h]:mm:ss`.  Also, it should be noted that your value of `3.504722222`, when set to cell format `[h]:mm:ss`, shows the correct result of `84:06:48`

Comment: @tigeravatar sorry, i updated that right after , since i tried moving where I put my formula.  it worked in the same column (A), but not in column B.  not positive why that works, btu it did

Comment: @Cyril As an aside, it must be `[h]:mm:ss` so the hours show beyond 24 hours, otherwise it only shows the remainder of 24 hours.  Since the remainder of 84/24 = 12, that's why `h` shows 12 where `[h]` shows 84

Comment: @tigeravatar makes sense; just started inspecting the values and it provides a date, so it's 12:06:48 on 1904/01/03, as opposed to formatted as you indicated.  i also just saw Jan's answer...

Comment: Hello, I reformatted my column values to `h:mm:ss` and once I summed my value I used `**[h]**:mm:ss`. I know have my desired result. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Greetings: please try format [h]:mm:ss

Comment: Hello, I reformatted my column values to `h:mm:ss` and once I summed my value I used **`[h]`**`:mm:ss`. I know have my desired result. Thanks all!